# fullPage.js scrollBar: true making the browser move with deelay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I use fullPage js script for my website. I have a problem.
I have some jquery that is changing my header elements when the visitor scrolls

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 1) {
    $("header").addClass("tab-2-header")
    $(".logo img").attr('src','http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/logo-negative.png')
    $("#menu li a:first").removeClass("active")
    $("#menu li").addClass("negative-dotts")
    $(".search img").fadeIn().attr('src','http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/search-negative.png')
    $(".search input").addClass("search-negative");
    } else {
    $("header").removeClass("tab-2-header")
    $(".logo img").attr('src','http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/logo-positive.png')
    $("#menu li a:first").addClass("active")
    $("#menu li").removeClass("negative-dotts")
    $(".search img").fadeIn().attr('src','http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/search.png')
    $(".search input").removeClass("search-negative");}
});
```

Basically this is the jquery that is changing my header.

All was working good till I had to make my website sectioned with fullpagejs. This script is hiding my scroll bar and if the scroll bar isnt visible, my jquery from above isnt starting because he doesn t know that the visitor is scrolling or because the scroll bar isnt visible.

In fullPagejs I can show the scrollbar so my header elements will show with :

```
scrollBar: true
```

If I add this line of code the scrollbar is visible and my jquery starts working.

The problem is that if I make the scroll bar visible, my website is going between sections with some lag (like framing). Any ideeas how I can solve this problem or If it s a posibility to hide the scroll bar but to be able to change my header on scroll ?

You can check the website without scrollbar here: http://bit.ly/1AGcZvd

And with scrollbar here: http://bit.ly/1C6VH8m

The one with scrollbar have some lag, deelay, I don t know how to name it ..
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use scroll bar to make it work.
If you are using `scrollBar:false`, then you should be using the callbacks provided by fullpage.js such as [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) which get executed after you reach a section.

You could even use the CSS class added by fullPage.js to the `body` element of the page on section change. And deal just with CSS for all it... which would be faster.

But if you still prefering to show the scrollBar and to deal with jQuery instaed of with CSS, then take into account that your code is being executed **hundreds of times** on every scroll and that's what causing the lag... you should better optimize it...

Something like this, which checks for a flag, would optimize it a lot:

```
var hasChanged = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 1 && !hasChanged) {
        $("header").addClass("tab-2-header")
        $(".logo img").attr('src', 'http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/logo-negative.png')
        $("#menu li a:first").removeClass("active")
        $("#menu li").addClass("negative-dotts")
        $(".search img").fadeIn().attr('src', 'http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/search-negative.png')
        $(".search input").addClass("search-negative");
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("tab-2-header")
        $(".logo img").attr('src', 'http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/logo-positive.png')
        $("#menu li a:first").addClass("active")
        $("#menu li").removeClass("negative-dotts")
        $(".search img").fadeIn().attr('src', 'http://verycreative.info/sebastian/img/search.png')
        $(".search input").removeClass("search-negative");
        
        hasChanged = true;
    }else{
        //whatever
        //...
        hasChanged = false;        
    }
});
```

And if you still want to improve it more, you could just use Javascript instead of jQuery.
But personally I would just deal with CSS.